# RPA using robotframework in springboot

Tags: java, python-3.x, spring-boot, robotframework, rpa

I have worked on java spring-boot but I don't have much knowledge about python so I was trying to have some worked around to make robotframework code trigger from springboot application and control robotframework code from springboot . My robotframework code has to do some simple task like opening a website and doing some clicks and other thing for that it uses python SeleniumLibrary.So it would be a great help if I can get the start of how to use robotframework code from springboot and how will robotframework use selenium library  if I dont have python on my system and other python library installed.Is it even possible to work with robot framework for RPA using springboot??

*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary    run_on_failure=NOTHING
Library    BuiltIn
Library    Collections
Test Timeout    10 minutes

*** Test Cases ***
Login Test
Set Robot Variables From Properties
${chrome_options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox

## Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --headless

```
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --start-maximized
Set Selenium Timeout    10sec
Open Browser   https://www.google.com/
```

I have triggered the above code from python flask but I want to try it with java springboot.And how to do security testing or vulnerability testing of RPA??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.